# how to run STRUCTURE command n times for each k value?

Tags: bash

I am running some STRUCTURE analysis and set  k = {1..10} by using this command (only 1 run for each K):

```
for k in seq 10
do
    python /home/ubuntu/bin/fastStructure/structure.py -K $k --input=../file.snps --output=snpl525D --format=str
done
```

Instead of 1 run for each K, now I want to get 15 runs for each K. could you please help me to modify the code above to do this job? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need.  Here, another `for` loop has been added inside the original loop.

```
for k in $(seq 10)
do
    # iterate 15 times for each k
    for n in $(seq 15)
    do
        python /home/ubuntu/bin/fastStructure/structure.py -K $k --input=../file.snps --output=snpl525D --format=str
    done
done
```

Depending on your preference, instead of `for n in $(seq 15)`, you can use `for n in {1..15}`.  They will give the same result.  This is similar to your existing loop `for k in $(seq 10)` which could also be `for k in {1..10}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `seq` call:

```
for k in $(seq 10); do
    for run in $(seq 15); do
        python /home/ubuntu/bin/fastStructure/structure.py -K $k --input=../file.snps --output=snpl525D --format=str
    done
done
```